# Почему в kong gateway не работают локальные адреса

Tags: nginx, docker

Установил [Kong Gateway (Enterprise) on Docker](https://docs.konghq.com/enterprise/2.5.x/deployment/installation/docker/)

В kong manager добавил сервисы и роуты, и все отлично работают кроме localhost.
Выдает сообщение **"message": "An invalid response was received from the upstream server"**, в контейнере kong - log **2021/10/07 15:17:22 [error] 29#0: *460886 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/", host: "localhost"**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по гуглив, в одной статье нашел что идет конфликт контейнера kong c localhost, вместо локалхоста нужно вставлять ip, командой **docker network inspect kong-ee-net** я определил этот ip, но результата это не принесло, все то же самое сообщение **"message": "An invalid response was received from the upstream server"**. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, уже 3 дня не могу понять как это исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь проксировать трафик через `Kong` в некий сервис, пусть для примера это будет `nginx`, то правильно `localhost` не будет работать, т.к. этот адрес будет указывать на контейнер с `Kong`, а там никакого сервиса нет.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, то вместо `localhost` вы можете указать `ip` контейнера/сервиса, например, `172.18.0.4` - это `ip` адрес `nginx` запущеного в другом контейнере. Узнать адрес можно через `docker inspect <container>`.

Или вы можете указать имя контейнера, если он запущен в одной `docker` сети, что и `Kong`. Например, если я запустил `nginx` с именем `test`, то `test` я и могу указать вместо `localhost`.

Comment: Ох спасибо, я добавил 192.168.0.12 host.docker.internal(установлен open server), и это сработало с моими локальными хостами. Если вам не сложно, не подскажите 192.168.0.12 что это за ip

Comment: @stas_8686 это обычный ip из приватной сети, все адреса из 192.168.x.x, являются часть приватной сети, её обычно раздают роутеры, виртуальные машины и т.д., и сам по себе ip ничего особо не значит, а важно, что это за сервер/сервис

Comment: Спасибо за помощь